# React Material-UI Sticky Table with Multiple Row Head and Dynamic Height

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI with React to display a table. I would like to use a sticky header for a multi-row table head and I do not want to set a height on my table. I want all lines of the header to stick to the top of the page.

I have an example of what is causing me trouble in the sandbox - when I scroll down I want the "Value" and the "Another Value" row (which are both in the table head) to stick to the top, only the last row of the header is sticking. So all rows of the header should stick. So however many rows there are in the table head they should all stick.

My actual problem may have either two or three rows in the head and the height of each row is not fixed.

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-roman-hqkpj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We got a solution for you:
`<TableCell style={{ top: "52px" }}>` , it's about adding 'top' css prop to each cell in second header row.
Also you can read next closed issue:
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/23090

Comment: I try it on Codesandbox and it works

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. Thanks for taking a look, seems like I should have opened an issue with material-ui myself. Alas I have now moved on from the project where I needed this solution!

Answer (score 0):

I still use the stickyHeader prop to get the correct visual styles but I do my "own" sticky behaviour. I also change the background color of the header to white by using the themes background paper variable.

```js
<TableContainer sx={{ height: "100%" }}>
    <Table size="small" stickyHeader>
        <TableHead
            sx={{
                position: "sticky",
                top: 0,
                zIndex: 1,
                "& .MuiTableCell-root": { backgroundColor: "background.paper" },
            }}
        >
```